# With sheet music, what happens with sharps and double sharps that are already sharpened in the key signature?

Tags: notation, sheet-music, accidentals

For example, let's say the key signature has an f sharp and then also an individual f note has a sharp next to it. Are they just emphasizing the f sharp or does that actually become a g?

Same question with a double sharp. If the key signature has an f sharp, and then there is an individual f with an x infront of it - is that supposed to be a g or a g sharp?

Comment: When you add a sharp to a Fis you geht a Fisis, no G, Although there are instruments like the piano where you would play this with the G key.

Comment: @ Aaron: concerning your edition.... there are no double sharps in the key signature.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It is just for emphasis.  It is usually just an instance where, in a recent measure in the piece, the F note had a natural attached to it.  The F-Sharp would be included in the following measure as a reminder that F is no longer natural, that it is back to the F-Sharp that it is in the key signature.

If there is an X next to a note, it is just a double sharp (F## or G natural).  I actually had trouble with that when I started studying music.  Basically the # from the key signature is included with the other # that is added to make a double sharp.  This is to add clarity for the person playing or studying the piece of music.

Comment: Accidentals are nulled after the end of the measure they appear, but yeah, this is done. (According to Wikipedia, sometimes these [courtesy accidental](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accidental_(music)#Courtesy_accidentals) marks appear in parentheses, although I don't recall ever seeing this.)

Comment: @neilfein Indeed! I have seen those in parentheses now that you mention it!

Comment: Take a look at this question about courtesy accidentals: http://music.stackexchange.com/q/5194/1678

Comment: Two cases at least have not been mentioned: 1) an F-sharp might be there to cancel an F double sharp.  2) When there are several staves (as in piano sheet music), an F-sharp might be indicated on one of them to enforce it despite the (temporary) use of a F-natural on another.

Comment: @ogerard: While accidentals are only applicable to the octave in which they are written, a performer who sees e.g. a G that's marked with a sharp played at the same time as another with no marking that would not be a sharp might wonder whether the lack of a sharp on the second note is a misprint.  Adding a natural would make that clearer.  Also, another place where courtesy accidentals are IMHO essential is when two parts on the same staff use the same line or space at different parts of the measure and the first has an accidental.  Performers will not *usually* notice an accidental for...

Comment: ...someone else's part, but performers who happen to notice an accidental at a given staff position might treat it as applying to theri part.  The only way to make things clear is to explicitly label the second note with some kind of accidental.

Comment: @supercat thanks for your further examples. I agree with you of course. Let's remember also that our current conventions are not identical to those followed by older composers in manuscripts and original editions.

Answer (score 4):

As well as a reminder that the F is sharp again, an F-sharp *mid*-bar might also be cancelling an F-natural earlier in the bar.

Answer (score 2):

Accidentals are not cumulative.   F# is F#. No matter it may already be stated in the key signature.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the possibly redundant sharps used anyway to indicate that the specific note is vital to the chord that's there.

As an example, your F# is making me think of the chord symbols A6 and A13.  Those would be common in the key of D, so there's no real need for the F# since it's native to D.  Yet if the composer wants the F# to be mandatory, no experimentation nor altering of it, he'll write it explicitly to make sure the chord gets the tonality he wants.  If the note is a necessary part of the melody, even moreso.